# binary data in application/json vs. multipart/form-data

Tags: json, content-type, api-design

It seems that binary data (from files) can be sent in HTTP requests that use either `Content-Type: application/json` or `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. I think JSON is more concise (less bytes) than the structure with boundaries for `multipart/form-data`. For transmitting binary data, is there anything that `multipart/form-data` can do that cannot be done (or done easily) in `application/json`?

Comment: Why not use the appropriate content type for your specific binary data? eg. `Content-Type: image/png` for an image, `Content-Type: video/mp4` for a video, etc.

Comment: Good call, @Asaph. Your point actually seems like a compelling reason to prefer `multipart/form-data`. In JSON I'm sure that can be derived and bundled into the JSON payload, but that seems like a lot of extra effort.

Comment: Do you have more than one binary object per response?